# Modify Maximum upload file size text

Tags: php, uploads

I have an issue with user uploading large images.  I have prevented this with this snippet...

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent');
function f711_image_size_prevent($file) {
    $size = $file['size'];
    $size = $size / 1024; // Calculate down to KB
    $type = $file['type'];
    $is_image = strpos($type, 'image');
    $limit = 5000; // Your Filesize in KB

    if ( ( $size > $limit ) && ($is_image !== false) ) {
        $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than '.$limit.'KB';
    }

    return $file;

}
```

This works great but the Media Upload page still shows text saying "Maximum upload file size: 64 MB"

I assume it pulls this value from the servers PHP config, is there a way to modify this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text is coming from [`wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1946`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L1946)

There is not filter is available to modify the text. But still if you wish you can use `gettext` filter to modify the text.

```
add_action('post-html-upload-ui', function () {
    add_filter('gettext', 'media_upload_limit_custom_text');
});
/**
 * Customize the max media size text
 * @param string $text
 * @return string $text
 */
function media_upload_limit_custom_text($text) {
    if ($text == 'Maximum upload file size: %s.') {
        return __('Image files must be smaller than 5000 KB', 'your-text-domain');
    }
    return $text;
}
```

We are adding `gettext` filter just before our text is being display!